# Regex for #else case in C preprocessor directive

Tags: regex, c-preprocessor

I want to find the `#else` case for certain a C preprocessor define.

Example:

```
#if defined(my_define)
  // multiple 
  // lines 
  // of 
  // code
#else
  // multiple 
  // lines 
  // of 
  // code
#endif
```

Or

```
#if defined (my_define)
  // same as above from here
```

But I do not want to match a case without `#else`:

```
#if defined(my_define)
  // multiple 
  // lines 
  // of 
  // code
#endif
```

I don't care for nested `#if`s, just the cases above.

I tried starting with

```
defined..?my_define.(\r\n|\r|\n)?
```

I don't know how to handle the arbitrary number of lines in between the directives.

Comment: While [it is possible](https://regex101.com/r/01lRfw/1), it looks really ugly.

Comment: Thank you. I slightly changed it to `#if defined..?my_define\b(?:(?!#(?:end)?if)[\s\S])*#else(?:(?!#(?:end)?if)[\s\S])*#endif` to include the defines name (and whitespace) and it works flawless :-) Feel free to write an answer, so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a tempered greedy token solution here:

```
#if defined..?my_define\b(?:(?!#(?:end)?if)[\s\S])*#else(?:(?!#(?:end)?if)[\s\S])*#endif
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/01lRfw/2)

**Details**:

- `#if defined` - a literla char sequence
- `..?` - any 1 or 2 chars other than line break char
- `my_define\b` - a whole word `my_define`
- `(?:(?!#(?:end)?if)[\s\S])*` - a *tempered greedy token* matching any char that is not a starting point for an `#endif` or `#if` literal char sequence
- `#else` - a literal char sequence
- `(?:(?!#(?:end)?if)[\s\S])*` - same as above
- `#endif` - a literal char sequence